# crontab jobs not running

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

My cronjob never runs. I installed crontab using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cron
```

I then ran `crontab -e` and added this to the bottom:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/app/monitor.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

However, my script never runs. My script is:

```
<?php
  file_put_contents('/var/testlog.txt', "EVERYTHING ONLINE\n", FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

When I just run `/usr/bin/php /var/app/monitor.php` myself in my terminal it adds to testlog.txt however after each minute when I check testlog.txt I do not see a new line from crontab running my script.

Comment: Are you sure `crond` service is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the command to run, the line must end in a new line (thus the file ends in a blank line). If it does not, it will ignore the line. That's a classic gotcha, and will cause the command to not run.